# Habilitar CORS em api rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cors, rails4

Esto usando esta **[GEM](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors)** para habilitar o *CORS* de minha aplicação.

O código que tenho em meu `config/application.rb` é o seguinte:

```
config.middleware.insert_before 0, 'Rack::Cors' do
  allow do
    origins 'http://localhost:8080'
    resource '*',
             headers: :any,
             methods: [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :options],
             max_age: 0
  end
end
```

O problema é que se altero alguma coisa nesta configuração e reinicio o server a configuração não se aplica.

Ex: Se eu remover o **:get** e reiniciar o server era para não estar liberado o *cors* para o *get* mas ele continua funcionando como se estivesse lá. O que poderia ser?

Comment: Você está seguindo [este exemplo?](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/blob/master/examples/rails4/config/application.rb) veja que é possível habilitar o debug e ver no logger como o CORS está sendo tratado

Answer (score 1):

Cheguei a instalar uma vez essa gem e também não funcionou comigo. Fazendo umas pesquisas no Google (não me lembro onde encontrei), achei um tutorial sobre como configurar o CORS sem uma gem. Neste caso. bastaria adicionar alguns métodos no `application_controller.rb`. Seria assim:

```
before_filter :cors_preflight_check
after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

protected

def cors_set_access_control_headers
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST,DELETE, GET, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS'
  headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
  headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
end

# If this is a preflight OPTIONS request, then short-circuit the
# request, return only the necessary headers and return an empty
# text/plain.

def cors_preflight_check
  if request.method == :options
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST,DELETE, GET, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
    render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
  end
end
```

Espero que isso ajude.

Answer (score 1):

No meu caso utilizo o Rails 5, eu criei um arquivo chamado cors.rb no config/initializers/cors.rb

porém coloquei assim:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors", :debug => true, 
:logger => (-> { Rails.logger }) do  
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', 
        :headers => :any, 
        :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :patch, :options, :head]
    end
end
```

que no meu caso é aberta minha api

e no arquivo de rodas, acrescentei do lado do nome do resource assim

```
resource :nome, :default => {format: :json}
```

e funcionou pra mim, tive diversos problemas com o CORS